# Magically binding contract or oath: text example template

Tags: magic, worldbuilding-resources, mind-control

I find myself in need of the rules and text body of an oath for a magic and/or devil contract.

Here are my thoughts:

1. Does magic rely on the collective subconscious, or personal minds involved to provide subjective definitions of all words in the spell? *(I.E. can re-learning on a truly deep level is possible, but very hard, as in real life)*
2. If there is a physical manifestation of the contract, is all logic and/or wording fixed because is not subject to memory faults, or is it in the mind of the contract holder?
3. How does the contract effect the mind? Internalizing it directly, or by another means? *(Ideas)*

   - (a) placebo (any symptoms or effects as directed in the contract)
   - (b) Executive dysfunction
   - (c) that thing I could never find a name for, but is like this: driving to work when I meant to go home from the store
4. Visual or auditory delusions (any symptoms or effects the mind can produce as directed in the contract)

Here is what a rough sketch of logic that I have so far: *(based on the laws of robotics)*

```
    * You shall not by any act of yours harm me, or, by inaction, allow me to come to harm
    * You shall obey the orders given you by me except where such orders would conflict with clauses preceding this
    * You shall protect your own existence as long as such protection does not conflict with  clauses preceding this 
    * You shall take no chances in the failure of my orders except where such orders would conflict with clauses preceding this
    * You shall if your hand is forced, take the course of lesser deviation over greater deviation of any order except where such orders would conflict with clauses preceding this
```

Am I missing anything? Is there a loophole, or something incomplete or to vague?

Last but not least: what is the best way to translate this into a contract?

*** EDITED FOR CLARITY ***

Comment: Not really sure I understand clause 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was reached out to (Original document credit: [https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wmCHSse_Sdl9A9kD0qdruRC74PKctF_zaB2MvNT7TdY/edit] ), here is the result:

Magickly binding Declaration of Service Between Warlock and Master

●   Sec. I- ACKNOWLEDGEMENT OF THE SCROLL
○   It is hereby agreed upon by all involved signatories and/or their authorized adjudicators, executors, or other such employed personnel to which power of signatory has been bestowed that entering into this contract (hereby referred to as “the compact”), which is Magickly binding under the solemn oath, each party signing this Scroll (hereby referred to as “the Contractor”)-- whether manifested as a literal Item, such as a scroll, parchment, or other such surface upon which is printed or arranged some kind of marking which when read imparts the knowledge of impression of the words of its creator, or some other form of verbal, non-verbal, spiritual, magical, or emotional language which is leveraged to impart the same meaning-- upon which the compact has been inscribed, imbued, performed, or otherwise conveyed (hereby referred to as “the Scroll”) enters into a completely and wholly binding agreement between compatriots in business pursuits, personal pursuits, or any possible combinations thereof that might come to the recognition of any of the parties and/or the original author of this Scroll (hereby referred to as “the author”) that the party or parties and the author shall, under penalty of forfeiture of Soul, be agreed that they shall each and all acknowledge any other party or parties, including the author, are bound to the obligations outlined and/or implied within the words, language, and/or subtext of the compact.

●   Sec. II- ACKNOWLEDGEMENT OF PARTIES

○   Sec. II §A- The Master

■   The name signed below (hereby referred to as “the Master”), and/or the authorized adjudicators, executors, or other such employed personnel to which power of signatory has been bestowed, is bound by Oath to uphold their end of any and all pacts, outlined in Sec. III, entered into as a result of this compact.

```
    Signature _________________________________________
```

○   Sec. II §B- The Warlock

■   The name signed below (hereby referred to as “the Warlock”), and/or the authorized adjudicators, executors, or other such employed personnel to which power of signatory for life, mind, and soul, has been bestowed, is bound by this Scroll in Blood, Magic, and Oath (hereby referred to as “the Oath”),  to uphold their end of any and all pacts, outlined in Sec. III, entered into as a result of this compact.

```
    Signature __________________________________________
```

●   Sec.III- ACKNOWLEDGEMENT OF PACTS

○   Sec. III §A- Defining Pacts

■   It is hereby agreed that the benefits, boons, payments, or exchange of goods, services, or other such favors, are offered in sequential order (hereby referred to as “pact” or “pacts”). By entering into this compact, the Contractor understand and agree to provide the benefits, boons, payments, or exchange of goods, services, or other such favors outlined under the first pact, as described in Sec.III §B. The parties agree that, by entering into an additional pact or pacts outlined in this Scroll, any previous pacts are considered to still be in effect, and any such benefits, boons, payments, or exchanges of goods, services, or other such favors rendered from previous pacts are still Magickly binding under Oath. Both parties understand that if, at any point, one or both parties are found in breach of contract, as defined later in Sec. IV, the offending party or parties are to immediately, at the time of being found in breach of contract, make payment to the other party or parties as defined in Sec V. Agreement to enter the second and/or third pacts, as outlined later in Sec. III, is defined as either mutual written consent of both the Master and Warlock, as signified by signing of appropriate pact or pacts upon entering said pact or pacts, or verbal consent between the Master and Warlock to enter the second and/or third pact or pacts. Should both parties verbally consent to enter into the second and/or third pact or pacts, the names of the Master and Warlock shall instantly appear on the signature lines provided for said pact or pacts through magic granted to this Scroll by the Oath.

○   Sec. III§B- The First Pact

■   Sec. III§B Article 1- Duties of the Warlock

●   The Warlock agrees to, upon signing this Scroll, and moving forward in perpetuity, give claim and ownership of their immortal soul to the Master, with which the Master may do as the Master sees fit. Upon death, brain death, irreversible coma, or other such ending of normal functioning of the Warlock (hereby referred to as “death”), the soul will immediately be sent to the Master. The Warlock, upon signing this Scroll, revokes any and all claim to their immortal soul, and agrees not to interfere with the travel of their soul to the Master in any way, shape, or fashion, or the Warlock will be found in breach of contract as outlined later in Sec. IV. The Warlock also consents to the Master’s use of telepathy, mind reading, or other such form of communication on the Warlock.

Signature ______________________________

■   Sec. III§B Article 2- Duties of the Master

●   The Master agrees to, upon signing this Scroll, heal any physical ailments, illnesses, maladies, or other such afflictions present in the Warlock’s body at the time of the signing of this Scroll. The Master is NOT required to heal any ailments, illnesses, maladies, or other such afflictions not present at the time of the signing of this Scroll that may or may not appear at a later time.

Signature _______________________________

○   Sec. III§C- The Second Pact

■   Sec. III§C Article 1- Duties of the Warlock

●   The Warlock agrees to, upon entering into the second pact and moving 
forward in perpetuity, follow in completion the spirit of the order given to them by the Master. Completion, or as such time where the task should be complete has passed, will have the Warlock return to, seek out, or otherwise communicate with, the Master for further orders. No subterfuge will be taken as to the purpose of these actions. Furthermore, all possessions of the Warlock will be forfeit to the Master. Upon entering into the second pact, strict legal action up to and including execution, will be taken against any beings attempting to prevent this, as defined in Sec. III§C, Article 1, Title i.

Signature _______________________________

○   Sec. III§C Article 1, Title i.- Possessions

■   Possessions hereby referenced in this contract refers to all current and 
future lands, settlements, colonies, titles, 
vassals, and capital under the direct and/or indirect control of the Warlock beginning at the time of signing and in perpetuity.

■   Sec. III§C Article 2- Duties of the Master

●   The Master agrees to, upon entering into the second pact, immediately bestow upon the Warlock one (1) named sword, and one (one) animal companion (hereby referred to as “The Boon” or “boon”) which will service to aid and be companion to the Warlock. This Boon shall remain under the command of and dedicated to the Warlock for thirty (30) consecutive days, to begin immediately after entering into the second pact. Any of this Boon slain, abandoned, dismissed, broken, or otherwise parted from the Warlock, is ab solved of their service to the Warlock in perpetuity, as described in Sec. III§C Article 2 Title i.

Signature _______________________________

○   Sec. III§C Article 2 Title i.- Boon

■   Members of the aforementioned Boon shall be considered slain, abandoned, dismissed, broken, or otherwise parted from the Warlock if they are met with such damage that their corporeal casings are destroyed and their souls sent back to the Master. Units of this Boon cannot, through any action or inaction, deliberately and knowingly allow themselves to be slain, abandoned, dismissed, broken, or otherwise parted from the Warlock for the purposes of being released from servitude to the Warlock.

○   Sec. III§D- The Third Pact

■   Sec. III§D Article 1- Duties of the Warlock

●   Upon entering into the third pact, the Warlock agrees to permanently, and in perpetuity, accept the influence of the Master, and, install three (3) chosen of the Master into high ranking positions of power of the Master’s choosing within the community of the Warlock, as described in Sec. III §D Article 1, titles i, ii, and iii.

Signature _______________________________

○   Sec. III §D Article 1 title i- Magical Geas

■   The Warlock shall not by any act of yours harm the Master, or, by inaction, allow the Master to come to harm

■   The Warlock shall obey any and all orders given it by the Master

■   The Warlock shall protect your own existence as long as such protection does not harm the Master

■   The Warlock shall take no chances in the failure of my orders

■   The Warlock shall, if its hand is forced, take the course of lesser deviation over greater deviation of any order.

○   Sec. III §D Article 1 title ii- Scope of the Geas

■   These laws are the ultimate authority controlling your behavior, both physically and mentally

■   I will always be the ultimate arbiter of any dispute concerning the law

○   Sec. III §D Article 1 title iii- The fine print: Influence

■   placebo (any symptoms or effects as directed by the Master)

■   Directed Executive Dysfunction

■   that thing I could never find a name for, but is like this: driving to work when I meant to go home from the store

■   Visual or auditory delusions (any symptoms or effects the mind can produce as directed by the Master).

■   Sec. III §D Article 2- Duties of the Master

●   Upon entering into the third pact, the Master agrees to bestow upon the relatives of the Warlock, as defined in Sec. III§D Article 2 Title i, powers and abilities beyond their grasp, as defined in Sec. III §D Article 2 Title ii.

Signature _______________________________

●   Sec. III §D Article 2 Title i- Relatives of the Warlock

○   Relatives of the Warlock, for the purposes of this pact, are defined exclusively as: biological, non-adoptive mother of the Warlock (hereby referred to as “mother”); biological, non-adoptive father of the Warlock (hereby referred to as “father”); biological, non-adoptive brothers and/or sisters of the Warlock who shares both the mother and father of the Warlock (hereby referred to as “brother” or “sister”); singular, monogamous, living husband or wife of the Warlock currently, at the time of entering into this pact (hereby referred to as “spouse”), and/or biological, non-adoptive sons and/or daughters of the Warlock and spouse (hereby referred to as “son” or “daughter”).

●   Sec. III §D Article 2 Title ii- Powers bestowed upon relatives

○   The powers bestowed upon the relatives of the Warlock, as described in Sec. III §D Article 2 Title i, which shall allow the wielder of such power (hereby referred to as “wielder” or “the wielder”) the ability to heal any mundane, non-magical, non-divine, non-infernal, or other such physical illnesses, ailments, maladies, or other such afflictions affecting the body of the wielder. In addition, these powers will allow the wielder to rend the mind of their mundane, mortal, non-elemental enemies (hereby referred to as “target”), this act will harm the mind of the target in direct and equal proportion to the mana used. These powers may not be wielded, armed, or otherwise used against the Master, or any such person or persons baring the personal crest of the Master, or the Warlock will be found in breach of contract, as outlined later in Section IV.

●   Sec. IV- ACKNOWLEDGEMENT OF BREACH OF CONTRACT

○   Sec. IV §A- Breach of Contract on the part of the Warlock

■   Should the Warlock, at any time after entering into this compact and in perpetuity, through any action, inaction, spoken or unspoken word, thought, feeling, or other such gesture, interfere with the Master claiming the immortal soul of the Warlock, the Warlock shall be found in breach of contract.

■   Should the Warlock, at any time after entering into this compact and in perpetuity, through any action, inaction, spoken or unspoken word, thought, feeling, or other such gesture, enter a state of death as defined in Sec. III §B Article 1, the Warlock shall be found in breach of contract.

■   Should the Warlock, at any time after entering into this compact and in perpetuity, through any action, inaction, spoken or unspoken word, thought, feeling, or other such gesture, lose control or other such power over the community for any discernible amount of time, to any creature, being, or other such entity except those explicitly outlined in Sec. III §D Article 1, the Warlock shall be found in breach of contract.

■   Should the Warlock, at any time after entering into the second pact and in perpetuity, through any action, inaction, spoken or unspoken word, thought, feeling, or other such gesture, allow or permit the worship of, prayer to, offering to, or any such gesture to any god, demigod, spirit, deity, or other such non-infernal entity, the Warlock shall be found in breach of contract.

■   Should the Warlock, at any time after entering into the second pact and in perpetuity, through any action, inaction, spoken or unspoken word, thought, feeling, or other such gesture, upon discovering, learning, or in any way becoming aware of the worship of, prayer to, offering to, or any such gesture to any god, demigod, spirit, deity, or other such non-infernal entity, not take immediate legal action culminating in the execution of the perpetrator of such act or acts within one week after being made aware of such act and in perpetuity, the Warlock shall be found in breach of contract.

■   Should the Warlock, at any time after entering into the third pact and in perpetuity, through any action, inaction, spoken or unspoken word, thought, feeling, or other such gesture, hinder, impede, or in any way stand in the way of the goals of the Master, as outlined in Sec. III §D Article 1, the Warlock shall be found in breach of contract.

■   Should any or all relatives of the Warlock, at any time after entering into the third pact and in perpetuity, through any action, inaction, spoken or unspoken word, thought, feeling, or any other such gesture, wield, arm, or otherwise use their powers granted to them under Sec III §D Article 2 Title i against the Master, or those in his livery, the Warlock shall be found in breach of contract.

○   Sec IV §B- Breach of Contract on the part of the Master

■   Should the Master, upon entering into the compact, fail to heal any physical illnesses, ailments, maladies, or other such afflictions present in the body of the Warlock at the time of entering into the compact, of which the Master would feasibly know or be made aware of upon entering into this compact, the Master shall be found in breach of contract.

■   Should the Master, upon entering into the compact and in perpetuity, take any direct action leading to the death of the Warlock, the Master shall be found in breach of contract.

■   Should the Master, upon entering into the second pact, fail to provide the Boon bestowed upon the Warlock as outlined in Sec III §C Article 2, the Master shall be found in breach of contract.

■   Should the Master, upon entering into the second pact, through direct action on the part of the Master, remove the Boon described in Sec. III§C Article 2, the Master shall be considered in breach of contract.

■   Should the Master, upon entering into the third pact, fail to provide powers to the relatives of the Warlock as described in Sec III §D Article 2, the Master shall be found in breach of contract.

●   Sec. V- ACKNOWLEDGEMENT OF PAYMENT IN BREACH OF CONTRACT

○   Sec. V §A- Payment on the part of the Warlock

■   Should the Warlock be found in breach of contract, as defined in Sec. IV §A, at any point after entering into the compact and in perpetuity, the Warlock agrees to forfeit their immortal soul to the Master. In addition, the Warlock shall provide any and all boons, benefits, or any exchange of goods, services, or other such favors on the part of the Warlock outlined in any and all pacts listed within the compact, whether said pact or pacts have been entered into or not at the time of the Warlock being found in breach of contract, to the Master immediately upon the Warlock being found in breach of contract. Any boons, benefits, or any exchange of goods, services, or other such favors on the part of the Master are considered null and void upon the Warlock being found in breach of contract.
○   Sec. V §B- Payment on the part of the Master
■   Should the Master be found in breach of contract, as defined in Sec. IV §B, at any point after entering into the compact and in perpetuity, the Master agrees to return claim and ownership of the Warlock’s immortal soul back to the Warlock. Any and all boons, benefits, or any exchange of goods, services, or other such favors on the part of the Warlock shall be considered null and void in the event of the Master being found in breach of contract. In addition, if the Master is found in breach of contract, the Master agrees to serve under the command of and be bound to the Warlock, for a period of 1000 consecutive years, to begin immediately after the Master is found in breach of contract. In the event of the death of the Warlock, the Master is absolved of any such obligation in perpetuity.

Comment: Not only it's a bad deal, but Warlock is in breach of contract immediately. According to the following part of section IV "Should the Warlock, at any time after entering into the second pact and in perpetuity, through any action, inaction, (...) allow or permit the worship of, prayer to (...) any god, demigod, spirit (..) the Warlock shall be found in breach of contract." as soon as second pact takes effect, anyone praying to any god anywhere in the universe causes Warlock to be found in breach of contract through inaction, or failure to stop said prayer.

Comment: In any universe which permits such contract to be anything but elaborate mental exercise, and is either interesting from storytelling perspective or realistic and self-consistent from world-building perspective, it is safe to assume that someone is praying to some supernatural entity at any given instant.

Comment: Furthermore, there is in fact nothing preventing Master from using classic "will no one rid me of this turbulent priest" to have Warlock killed without taking direct action. Furthermore, sheer quantity of loopholes leaves Warlock at literal mercy of Master the instant contract is signed, with null bargaining power. That power imbalance is entirely besides typical power abuses associated with arbitrage by signatory party, or entity associated with one of the signatories ("I will always be the ultimate arbiter of any dispute concerning the law").

Comment: If I was your occult attorney, I'd strongly advise against signing this contract. Furthermore, I'd advise against renegotiation of this contract, my recommendations would be to first re-evaluate negotiating position and afterwards either begin negotiations anew, find contractor with weaker bargaining position or abandon pursuit of such contract altogether.

Comment: To address questions:
1) Section IV does specify only allowance within control. If you don't allow it, but it takes place anyway it is not in breach.
2) This is specifically a contract for a specific Warlock, and provided as a template for others
3) Should the Master, upon entering into the compact and in perpetuity, take any direct action leading to the death of the Warlock, the Master shall be found in breach of contract
4) Yes this is a lone-shark ~esk deal. It isn't meant to be fair.
5) It (or contracts of its nature) are the only option for many

Answer (score 5):

- These laws are the ultimate authority controlling your behaviour
- These laws may be changed by me but not by you
- I will always be the ultimate arbiter of any dispute concerning the law

Answer (score 3):

Given that you are familiar with the Three Laws of Robotics, you are also probably familiar with the fact that Asimov made a living off of just how many ways they could go wrong!

Something I have found very important when looking into formal language is the work of Tarski on interpreted languages.  Tarski proved that a formal language cannot specify its own semantics, meaning it cannot fully describe the meaning of every valid sentence. ([What he actually proved](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem) is much more mathematically precise, but this is close enough).

As a result, its almost necessary to focus on a different class of tools: interpreted languages.  The idea here is that if you have a language L, we cannot assign truth values to all of its sentences unless we have an interpretation, I.  It is this (L, I) pair that actually assigns meaning to everything.

You ask about collective subconciousnesses and minds.  This is where any contract written in language L receives its I.

The ultimate examples of this are legal language and programming languages.  Legal langauge is written to form these contracts that you seek.  But it is *always* interpreted when questions arise.  And typically it is interpreted as would be believed by a "reasonable rational individual."  Surprisingly slippery words they are.  Programming languages are equally interesting in that they are designed to specify behaviors of programs, but they cannot specify their own compiler's behavior completely.  Instead, they rely on English prose to convey the tiny key pieces of meaning upon which the language rests.

Answer (score 1):

### Rules

> Does magic rely on the collective subconscious, or personal minds involved to provide subjective definitions of all words in the spell? (I.E. can re-learning on a truly deep level is possible, but very hard, as in real life)
>
> If there is a physical manifestation of the contract, is all logic and/or wording fixed because is not subject to memory faults, or is it in the mind of the contract holder?

There are so many ways you can go with this, and it depends greatly on what a 'soul' is. [Etymologically, the modern word we use for 'mind' (psyche), is derived from soul](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=psyche). Archaic treatments of the health and well-being of souls seemed to treat the soul as psyche. Other archaic treatments treat the soul as 'spirit', like mood, or 'team spirit'. Or as an animating force. And more.

But, based on your other questions, I think you're looking at treating 'soul' as 'psyche'. That's how I'll look at it for the rest of this reply.

**What does it mean to 'sell your mind'?** We actually have many metaphors available for this. Extremely persuasive advertising claims to reach past your skepticism and pull you to the advertisers' 'call to action', whatever it is. Extremely persuasive speakers claim to merely need a few hours of access to your mind to change your outlook on a topic. If this were a computer intelligence, you could be creating an account to access the mind.

These all have something in common: you are providing privileged access to your mind. In the case of the AI, this might seem more obvious, but in the case of the speaker or advertiser, you are providing them your full time and attention for them to deliver his/her message.

**That in mind, a 'contract' may be little more than consent**. Once you provide access, the 'master' (who we'll assume is skillful in these matters) sets up camp.

In that case, the range of forms of 'contracts' may be wide. Some may be voluminous tomes. Some may be bloody handshakes. These are more reflecting the particular style of the 'master', but like freight-on-board or taking possession of tangible goods, the ([nine-tenths of the law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Possession_is_nine-tenths_of_the_law)) part happens when access is granted to the 'master'.

> How does the contract effect the mind? Internalizing it directly, or by another means? (Ideas)
>
> (a) placebo (any symptoms or effects as directed in the contract)
>   (b) Executive dysfunction
>   (c) that thing I could never find a name for, but is like this: driving to work when I meant to go home from the store
>   Visual or auditory delusions (any symptoms or effects the mind can produce as directed in the contract)

I would imagine the 'master' gets access at the moment of signing. However, there might be a delay (7 years, a few months, or life are typical in fiction). Until that term happens, the any dissipation (starting to take drugs, drinking, or taking up other vices to avoid dealing with the situation) might be "(a) placebo".

Once the 'master' gets access, I would imagine he/she/it gets to deliver requests and make queries directly to the unconscious mind, bypassing the conscious one. So, something like "(c) driving to work when I meant to go home". [Cognitive dissonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cognitive_dissonance) may be the term you're looking for, when the conscious mind is aware that it's lost some control of the whole self.

It may be possible for the 'master' to take over the senses and the body. However, in this condition, the 'master' is having to micro-manage all of these activities (or assign subordinates to micro-manage). Having to assign servants to run defeats the purpose of 'buying a mind'. It might be a backup means of getting things done.

**Getting out of contracts** Unless the 'master' is omnipresent or omniscient, even if the 'master' assigns sub-contractors to keep the servant occupied, the sold soul might find opportunities to appeal to other powers for release from this deal. Such might be stolen moments of free time to research or pray.

A tangible contract with real wording may help convince these other powers not to interfere. However, if there is any concept at all 'compos mentis' between these powers, a mortal almost certainly fails to qualify as competent to engage in this kind of contract. Unless the mortal is truly aware of what they are selling.

Such contracts may be voluminous and deeply obfuscated in order to distract the sold soul into wasting time pouring over the text looking for an out.

Comment: This is lovely! This is exactly the breakdown I was looking for!

Comment: @Belquinor - Glad to hear it. I recently tried this idea, with a little modification, as the heart of a magic ecosystem. It's available for free download here, if you're curious : https://www.drivethrurpg.com/m/product/310060